# Click on YouTube subscribe button not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Click on YouTube subscribe button not working

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the YouTube channel page
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/your_channel_id")

# Switch to the first iframe on the page
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

# Wait until the subscribe button is visible
subscribe_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "paper-button#subscribe-button"))
)

# Click on the subscribe button
subscribe_button.click()

# Switch back to the main content
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I have tried this code but it not working

Comment: What did you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: I want to click on the YouTube subscribe button to get subscribed

Comment: And what actually happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I have tried to click subscribe button by xpath,css selecter it not clicking it

Comment: File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\gologin_selenium\main.py", line 76, in <module>
    subscribe_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until

Comment: I think it error like path not found but actually exist

Comment: Are you sure?  When I look at the DOM of that page, I don't find that selector at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use move_to_element to scroll to the item before clicking on it. Selenium can only click on items that are visible on the screen. Also, you may want to change the condition from “visibility_of_element_located” to “presence_of_element_located”. Try adding this line before subscribe_button.click():

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

subscribe_button = WebDriverWait.EC.presence_of_element_located(driver, 10).until(
   EC.((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "paper-button#subscribe-button")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(subscribe_button).perform()
subscribe_button.click()
```

This may solve your problem!